# Getting two separate divs to delay at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

I am running into two separate issues.

1. I want two divs to start delaying at the same time. My `text-button` div does not delay at all.
2. I am trying to get my `text-button` div to animate up within the parent div 'gray' 100px, but it moves the parent div instead of the `text-button` div.

What am I doing wrong for this not to work?

```js
$(function(){
$('#text').delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
$('#text-button').delay(2000).fadeIn(2200);
$('#text-button').animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
 }
#text {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 25%;
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
 }
 #text-button {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
   wdith: 100%;
   /*display: inline;*/
   line-height: 2em;
   padding: 0 10px;
   text-align: center;
   top: 90%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gray">
  <div id="text">text delay.</div>
  <div id="text-button">text delay 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: text-button is not hidden by css, i think you would want to do this if you are fading it in?

Comment: Wow, I missed that. Do you have any idea about the animate?

Comment: with a quick look, it seems you are originally using relative positioning and `top`, but then you try to change the margin. it seems like you should be changing the `top` instead... or something, maybe using a div nested in an relative positioned div and changing the margin within that

Comment: Perfect! `top` did it. Do you know how I could get my `text-button` border to not the the entire `width: 100%` without setting the width to a lower amount? I want this to be responsive, so I don't want to set specific widths for each media query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, like a lower percentage width?

Comment: I want the border to go around only the wording I have. Ideally I want the border to be only as big as the padding I implemented. I don't want the border to be sized by the width I have for that div.

Comment: Oh, I would wrap the text in a span and then put the border/padding css in `#text-button span` instead of directly on `#text-button`...also fyi you spelled `width` wrong in your css

Comment: The span worked perfectly. Thanks for all of your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the `delay`, it's that the div isn't hidden initially with css - so the `fadeIn` has no affect.

The problem with moving the div is that you are using a relative positioning with `top` and then trying to change the margin. There are several ways you could do this. One would be just to change `top` instead.

To make the border for the bottom text not go all the way across, I would just wrap it in a span and put the border/padding css on that...

All together something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d5d6z35/)

```
$(function() {
  $('#text').delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
  $('#text-button').delay(2000).fadeIn(2200);
  $('#text-button').animate({
    'top': '80%'
  }, 1000);
});
```

.

```
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#text {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 25%;
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#text-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  top: 90%;
}

#text-button span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

.

```
<div class="gray">
  <div id="text">text delay.</div>
  <div id="text-button"><span>text delay 2</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!!